# Unable to update NSMutableDictionary initialized with the NSUserDefauts value

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I used NSUserDefaults to save NSMutableDictionary. But when I am retrieving the value from the NSUserDefaults, I am unbale to modify/update the values of the NSMutableDictionary into which I am saving the values.

Need some suggestion on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get non-mutable instances of `NSDictionary` from `NSUserDefaults`. To make them mutable, you need to do something like this:

```
dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
myMutableDict = [dict mutableCopy];
// Note that the retain count is +1, so you will need to
// release or autorelease myMutableDict later on.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also save to a plist.

This is how you write to a plist:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * dataFilePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.dat"]

NSMutableDictionary * newLocalPlist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// add your prefs here

[newLocalPlist writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];
[newLocalPlist release];
```

And this is how you read from a plist:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * dataFilePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.dat"]
NSMutableDictionary * lastLocalPlist = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath] autorelease];
```